# Add a horizontal Navigation bar with limit and place other items under '...'

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a navigation bar with multiple list items. Limit number of button on the main view to 6 buttons and the remainder of the pages get placed under "..." menu.

I am able to create horizontal bar , I want to know how to limit it to 6 button and place remaining under '...'

I am fetching the data from DB and inside for loop i am creating the buttons in navigation panel. However i want to limit it to 6 button and the other items should be placed under '...'. When we select an item from '...', it should appear on screen. If i get any sample code for this will also be helpful.

Below is the code, not sure if it will be helpful for debug.
[image: required css]

```
for (var j = 0; j < memberNavigationList.$values.length; j++) {
                var jitem = memberNavigationList.$values[j];
                var url = integra_tolower(integra_trim(APPPATH + jitem.URL));
                var currenturl = integra_tolower(integra_trim(self.location.href));
                if ((jitem.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf('emr/summary/visitdock') != -1 || jitem.URL.toLowerCase() == 'applications/encounternote.aspx') && jitem.PreviousVisit != '' && jitem.PreviousVisit.length > 10) {
                    sidebar_nav.push('<li id="menuTertairyItemId_' + j + '" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;"  onmouseover="$ic.tertiaryNav.Showtooltip(this);"  onclick="openVisitFromNavbar(\'')
                    sidebar_nav.push(jitem.PreviousVisit + '$' + jitem.PreviousVisitDate + '$' + EMRContextApplicationId);
                    if (jitem.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf('emr/summary/visitdock') != -1) {
                        sidebar_nav.push('\'' + ',' + '\'' + jitem.URL);
                    }


                    sidebar_nav.push('\');"');
                    sidebar_nav.push('data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="' + jitem.Description + '" class="myTip btn pull-left ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray ' + ' ');

                }  else {
                    if (jitem.Indented === true) {
                        sidebar_nav.push('<li id="menuTertairyItemId_' + j + '" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;" onclick="$ic.tertiaryNav.menuItemClicked(this,\'' + url + '\',\'' + jitem.URL.toUpperCase() + '\',\'' + jitem.description + '\',\'' + jitem.PageType + '\');" onmouseover="$ic.tertiaryNav.Showtooltip(this)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="' + jitem.Description + '" class="myTip ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray btn pull-left '  + '');
                    } else {

                        sidebar_nav.push('<li id="menuTertairyItemId_' + j + '" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;" onclick="$ic.tertiaryNav.menuItemClicked(this,\'' + url + '\',\'' + jitem.URL.toUpperCase() + '\',\'' + jitem.description + '\',\'' + jitem.PageType + '\');" onmouseover="$ic.tertiaryNav.Showtooltip(this)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="' + jitem.Description + '" class="myTip ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray btn pull-left ' + '');
                    }
                }

                if (currenturl.indexOf(url) > -1 || (currenturl.match(/addpatientencounter.aspx/g) && url.match(/patientencounters.aspx/g))) {
                    sidebar_nav.push(' ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray-active ');
                } else {
                    if (url.indexOf("popover") > -1) {
                        sidebar_nav.push(' ic2-flowsheet-btn-green ');
                    } else {
                        sidebar_nav.push('  ');
                    }
                }               
               

                sidebar_nav.push('">');
                sidebar_nav.push('<a href="#"></a>'+jitem.Description);
                sidebar_nav.push('</li>');
            }
        }
        
        

        sidebar_nav.push('</ul>'); // close the sidebarnav
```